# Case-sensitive string comparison in Puppet

Tags: regex, string, puppet

The [Puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_conditional.html) indicates that the language's string comparisons with `==` are case-insensitive. What can I do when I need case-sensitive string comparisons? Is there a better way than taking refuge in regular expressions like so:

```
if $string =~ /^VALUE$/ {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: Your interpretation is accurate and you will have to use regexps to do case sensitive matching on strings.

Comment: Well, regexes are probably the *cleanest* way, but not the only one.  You can use an ERB template, for example, or write a custom function.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thx. If you want to turn your comment/confirmation into an answer, I shall accept it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger By ERB template, do you mean doing the string comparison inside the template?

Comment: Exactly, @MattSchuchard, with the template being evaluated via the `inline_template()` function.  With ERB, you can do anything that Ruby can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the intrinsic Puppet DSL, you cannot do case sensitive string comparisons with the `==` operator. You must use the regular expression operator `=~` to perform case sensitive string comparisons.

However, as @JohnBollinger has pointed out, you can write a custom function to do this for you by leveraging Ruby's case sensitive string comparison with its `==` operator: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/functions_ruby_overview.html.

The custom function would look something like:

```
# /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/mymodule/lib/puppet/functions/mymodule/stringcmp.rb
Puppet::Functions.create_function(:'mymodule::stringcmp') do
  dispatch :cmp do
    param 'String', :stringone
    param 'String', :stringtwo
    return_type 'Boolean' # omit this if using Puppet < 4.7
  end

  def cmp(stringone, stringtwo)
    stringone == stringtwo
  end
end
```

You can then utilize this custom function like:

```
if stringcmp($string, 'VALUE') {
  # ...
}
```

given your code from above, and the string comparison will be case sensitive.